# Java heap size growing to 10x the used heap

Tags: java, jvm, profiling

I am profiling a Java process with VisualVM and I found out that while my used heap remains constantly below 100 MB, the heap size keeps increasing to a point at which it is 10 times bigger than the used heap!

Reading from the docs:

> By default, the virtual machine grows or shrinks the heap at each
>   collection to try to keep the proportion of free space to live objects
>   at each collection within a specific range. This target range is set
>   as a percentage by the parameters -XX:MinHeapFreeRatio= and
>   -XX:MaxHeapFreeRatio=, and the total size is bounded below by -Xms and above by -Xmx.

So, consindering that `MinHeapFreeRatio` and `MaxHeapFreeRatio` are set to 40% and 70% respectively, why is this happening?

[image: VisualVM screenshot]

Comment: you should enable GC logging and look at the logs. Maybe visualvm is not accounting for the occupancy of objects that die in eden.

Comment: When the GC behaves in surprising ways, it can be due to a combination of command line paramemters you have used. I would try this again with what you believe is the minimum to run the process.

Comment: I have been now running this process for days with `-Xmx128m`, without experiencing any memory error nor performance degradation, so it's still hard to understand why the JVM kept enlarging the heap when Xmx was not set.
@PeterLawrey I hadn't set any other JVM parameter.

Comment: The default maximum is 1/4 of main memory. I agree that the JVM doesn't appear to need it and shouldn't be growing the way it is.